# ADFS SSO Anonymous Home Page MVC 4 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on, adfs

I have been looking for the answer to this, but it is admittedly a difficult concept to phrase at Google. 
I have several MVC sites using our ADFS to authenticate using single-sign-on. It works well. However, I am wondering if it is possible to have a home page which allows anonymous users to access some features without being logged in. I have seen people referring to redirecting users to the anonymous home page after single-sign-out from the relying party. Basically, can I secure half the application using ADFS SSO?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
     <connectionStrings>
    
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://sts.testsite.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:Realm" value="https://localhost:44301" />
    <add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="https://localhost:44301" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.cshtml">
    </customErrors>
    
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <runtimes here.../>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://localhost:44301" />
      </audienceUris>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="http://sts.testsite.com/adfs/services/trust">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="AA6032061B0E74B3B5B0D495DC7C55B18B0862A4" />
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="http://sts.testsite.com/adfs/services/trust" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://sts.testsite.com/adfs/ls/" realm="https://localhost:44301" requireHttps="true" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
  
</configuration>
```

This is the Global.asax.

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Email;
    }
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
    }
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var error = Server.GetLastError();
        var cryptoEx = error as CryptographicException;
        if (cryptoEx != null)
        {
            FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
            Server.ClearError();
            if (Request.Cookies["StoreNumber"] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie storeNumber = Request.Cookies["StoreNumber"];
                storeNumber.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you add [AllowAnonymous] to the controllers/actions that should allow anonymous users, does that not work?

Comment: It does not seem to stop the STS from attempting to authenticate before allowing access. I tried it with my application. It goes to the authenticating server before doing anything else in the application.

Comment: Can you post your web.config?  There might be some default content in there that causes this behavior.

Comment: I added the web config. I removed connection strings, run times, and error handling to save space and because I didn't they they were relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should behave the way you want by default.  Most likely what is happening is that this setting in your web.config is causing it to require everyone to log in, because this is an explicit deny to anonymous users.  Try removing it and see if it then works as you want.

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

In theory, you also should not need the following lines, if you have put `[Authorize]` on any controller that requires authorization/login.  It should be allowing anonymous users to access the `AccountController` once you remove the deny.  You should be able to control which controllers/methods require authorization with `[Authorize]` and `[AllowAnonymous]` alone.

```
<location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: I removed both those sections and the application works exactly like it has always been. It still requires authentication even for `[AllowAnonymous]` notated controllers.

Comment: Are you using IISExpress locally?  Is it possible that IIS Express is disallowing anonymous as well?  If you are using visual studio, you can click on the project and view the Properties window, which has an Anonymous Authentication field that should be set to Enabled.  This should update the csproj file so that it no longer contains 'disabled' here:      <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>

Comment: I have tested it locally and deployed on the live server. Anonymous authentication was set to "Enabled" already both for IISExpress and on the IIS server.

Comment: Are you adding a global Authorize filter in your global.asax?  I am trying to determine why it would be issuing a 401 response which then causes it to redirect to the STS.  If you do have one there, does removing it resolve anything?  Is it possible that there are ACLs on the directories in your app that are preventing access to anonymous?

Comment: There is no global Authorize filter and, to my knowledge, no ACLs. I will add my Global filters to my question in case you see something I miss.

Comment: What is in FilterConfig?  How does the app behave if you turn off passiveRedirect in your web.config?

Comment: Ha! The FilterConfig was it! `filters.Add(new ValidateStoreNumberAttribute());` was a filter referring to a custom filter I had that verified a user's attributes were all in the correct format before allowing them to continue else it forced them to log in again. Thank you very much! Your answer was correct if I hadn't had the custom filter. For others' reference, when I turned off passiveRedirect the application immediately returned a 401 error.